# error while setting webhook url in developers.facebook

Tags: facebook, nestjs, facebook-messenger-bot

i encountered this error while setting webhook callback url in developers.facebook for my messenger bot. [image]

The messenger bot works fine locally forwarding port with ngrok but while using the remote server url, it throws the error. Other bots like viber and telegram are working fine.

**note** :

1. Viber and telegram are running on the same port. messenger bot is runnin in a different port. Still all the ports are exposed from the server.

Implementation of messenger and other bots :

```
  const botTelegram = app.get(TelegramBotService).getBot()
  const botViber = app.get(ViberBotService).getBot()
  const botMessenger = app.get(MessengerBotService).getBot()
  const botWhatsapp = app.get(WhatsappBotService).getBot()
  app.use(botTelegram.webhookCallback("/telegram/webhook"))
  app.use("/viber/webhook", botViber.middleware())
  botMessenger.start(3001)
```

My messengerbot service :

```
@Injectable()
export class MessengerBotService {
    private readonly messengerBot : any
    private readonly downloadFolderPath = join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'downloads');

    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Message.name) private messageModel : Model<MessageDocument>,
        @InjectModel(User.name) private userModel : Model<UserDocument>,
        private realTimeGateway : RealTimeGateway
    ){
        this.messengerBot = new BootBot({
            accessToken : process.env.MESSENGER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            verifyToken : process.env.MESSENGER_VERIFY_TOKEN,
            appSecret : process.env.MESSENGER_APP_SECRET,
            webhook : '/messenger/webhook'
        })


        this.messengerBot.on('message', async(payload, chat) =>{
// remaining working functionalities
```